# Sparse Multidimensional Array taking huge space - HashTable better?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, hashtable, heap-memory, space-complexity

Is there a better approach to use of Multidimensional Arrays to compute values to be displayed in a table. Please note each of the dimension of the array is huge but is sparse. Can something like a HashTable be considered?

Output Table after the computation looks like this

[image: Output Table after the computations]

Comment: Answer to your question is: *Maybe.* Post doesn't contain enough information to give any reasonable solution.

Comment: no, show us some code how you allocate the array and access it. Maybe you want to use a onedimensional array and calculate the offset to the next row yourself.

Comment: Does your multidimensional array have any special properties?  Sparse?  Symmetric?  These can help cut the required space.

Comment: Yes it is sparse! Please see the edited version.

Comment: Your data does not apear to be sparse.  IMHO you probably shouldn't start using sparse matrix techniques unless at least half your entries are 0, and maybe not even then.  Have you considered creating a database and making database calls?

Comment: @Degustaf The table I have given is not the input. Its the resultant table I'm populating in near real time. The multidimensional array is fairly sparse as I mentioned. Or somehow can I limit what I put on the memory so that it is not sparse anymore? That is why I'm considering HashTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is outdated, because the OP added the information, that the data is a sparse matrix**

---

Not really. Maybe a one dimensional array (would save the pointers to the dimensions - but that's err... pointless).

An array is the data structure with the fewest metadata (because there is no metadata at all). So your approach can't be optimized much, if you really need to store all that data in memory.

Any other data structure (tree, linked lists, etc.) would contain extra metadata and would therefore consume more memory.

The only way for you to use less memory is to actually *use less* memory (by only loading the data into memory you really need and leaving the rest on your hard drive or whatever).

You want to display a table, so maybe you can limit the rows you save in memory to an area slightly bigger than the viewport of your table (so you can scroll through the table fluently). Then you can dynamically compute and overwrite the rows according to the scroll state of your table.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to manage memory for a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).  I would start by defining a struct to hold an individual entry in your matrix

```
struct sparse_matrix_data{
    int i;
    int j;
    int /* or double or whatever */ value;
};
```

so that you would store the two indices and the value for each non-zero entry.  From there, you need to decide what data structure works best for the computations you need to do:  hash table on one or both indices, array of these structs, linked list, ...

Note that this will only decrease the memory required if the additional memory required to store the indices is less than the memory you used to store the zeros in your original multidimensional array.